# HTML2Canvas capture modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

I have this code below which consists of a `HTML tab` and a button which opens my modal. The problem is that i am using the library `HTML2canvas` and i am trying to capture `my HTML tab` with the modal below it, i have put my modal code inside my `capture div` but it doesn't appear in the picture when i download it.

Is what i'm trying to do possible to accomplish? Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```js
function sendData() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('capture'), {
    allowTaint: false,
    useCORS: true
  }).then(function(canvas) {
    $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    $('#test').attr('download', 'Test.png');
    $('#test')[0].click();
  });
}


function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-bottom: 8px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
}

.jobs-panel {
  display: table;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: #b7bcbe;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.tabwidth {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="capture">
    <div class="jobs-panel">

      <button class="modal-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">MODAL BUTTON</button>

      <div class="tabwidth">
        <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Pikachu')" id="defaultOpen">Pikachu</button>
        </div>

        <div id="Pikachu" class="tabcontent">
          <img src="https://s22.postimg.cc/l2txqenox/Pikachu.png" width="300" height="300" crossorigin>
        </div>

        <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
          <h3>Paris</h3>
          <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
          <h3>Tokyo</h3>
          <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h2 class="modal-title center">FAQ</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="central">
              <h3 class="bold-text ">QUESTIONS
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="match-button" onclick="sendData();">capture</button>
  <a id="test" href="#"></a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding a helper function for downloading image in this way:

```
`https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBGaMP`
```

Here is the link where i found the downloadCanvas function code:

[https://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/7PRNN/](http://%20%20%20%20https://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/7PRNN/)

Greetings, hope it helps.

Comment: That link just download the image codeproject. What i'm trying to accomplish is i want my modal to be captured together with the HTML tab.

Comment: Do you want to capture entire screen? Am I understand you right?

Comment: Yes i want to capture then entire screen with my modal view inside of it.

Comment: You want to capture the dialog bellow the other content, when in the screen it is closed. Is that right?

Comment: i want to capture the modal view without pressing the modal button.

Comment: For example when you click capture, you want to capture the opened dialog?

Comment: Yes and i also want the tab to be in the image as well.

Comment: Here it is some answer for your problem, the same link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBGaMP. If you want to remove timeout you need to change bootstrap styles about dialog animations in some cases. Greetings.

Comment: Thats awsome but isit not possible to put the modal below so it wont block my tab?

Comment: Just make its position relative, another part of this task is only in scope of css.

Comment: sorry which part do i make which part relative?

Comment: div with class "modal" should be with position relative

Comment: Nice by changing the modal position relative made it work! But how do i make it so that only when i click the button the modal position will change to relative.

Comment: When click you should attach css class to parent element in which selections scope this div will be relative, after that you should remove this class.

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
import { useScreenshot } from 'use-react-screenshot'
```

instead to capture the image of component.
Working fine in react.